# MS Access97 Run Time Error 2447

Tags: database, ms-access, runtime

Someone left a system using MS Access97 and I dont have any idea on how to use access97 since it is my first time using it.

I installed a Microsoft Access97 to a new computer then try to open the system but it displays an error "Run Time Error 2447 There is an invalid use of the .(dot) or ! operator or invalid parenthesis". However the old computer can open the database without any error. I am really confused about this scenario. Can anyone help me?

Answer (score 0):

Open the code editor. Go to menu **Tools, References** and check that no reference is prefixed MISSING. If so, resolve it.

In any case, go to the menu and select **Compile and save all modules**.

If some ocx or third-party control is installed and used on the old computer, you must install these on the new computer as well.